# Multiplying numpy array stack with hermitian transpose of itself without loop

Tags: numpy, vectorization

I want to completely get rid of for loops in my code.

I have a complex numpy array **stack1** of dimension OxMxN This is a stack of MxN arrays stacked in the 1st dimension. For each MxN array that we call **A** I want to compute the matrix multiplication:

```
for k in range(stack1.shape[0]):
    A=stack1[k,:,:]
    newstack[k,:,:]=A.dot(  numpy.conj(numpy.transpose(A))  )
```

I tried

```
newstack = stack1 @ np.conj(stack1.T)
```

but I run in an issue because the dimensions won't match

Comment: you don't want a full default transpose.  You want a partial one, changing the (O,M,N) to (O,N,M).

Comment: Read the documentation for `matmul` and for `transpose`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use [`einsum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) -

```
np.einsum('ijk,ilk->ijl',stack1,np.conj(stack1))
```

We can also use [`np.matmul`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.matmul.html) -

```
np.matmul(stack1,np.conj(stack1).swapaxes(1,2))
```

On `Python 3.x`, simplifies with `@` operator -

```
stack1 @ np.conj(stack1).swapaxes(1,2)
```

Comment: Seriously, if you're doing complex field math like the questioner apparently is, you probably already know Einstein Summation Notation.  Get good at `np.einsum`.  Not only is it shorter to write and often faster (especially with `optimize = True`), your code will be infinitely easier to parse by others in your field.

Comment: `/einsum_soapbox`

Answer (score 0):

Just try to correct your for loop

```
a=[]
for k in range(stack1.shape[0]):
    A=stack1[k,:,:]
    a.append(A.dot(  numpy.conj(numpy.transpose(A))  ))

np.array(a)
Out[399]: 
array([[[0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.]],
       [[0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.]]])
```

Comment: I would like to avoid loops completely